# Prove that $f(a) \leq f(x) \leq f(b) $

Tags: derivatives

If the following data are given, prove that $f(a) \leq f(x) \leq f(b) $

f is differentiable on [a,b] and f'(x) $ \geq  0 \forall x \in (a,b) $

Is the following argument correct?

$f'(x) \geq 0 \implies f $ is increasing on (a,b) $ \implies f(a) \leq f(b) $

Let $x_0 \in (a,b) $

Since f is increasing $f(a) \leq f(x_0) \leq f(b) $
 $$ \therefore \forall x \in (a,b)  f(a) \leq f(x) \leq f(b) $$

Comment: You may want to use the mean value theorem to make things a bit more rigorous.

Comment: There is something missing: $f'(x) ≥ ?$

Comment: $f$ can be differentiable on $(a,b)$. We need it to be continuous on $[a,b]$. Then you can use that argument, yes.

Comment: f is differentiable on (a,b) $\implies $ f is continuous on (a,b) $\implies $ f is continuous on [a,b] right?

Comment: I'm not sure that the claim that a non-negative derivative implies the function to be increasing is actually easier than the original claim. Therefore (if you haven't already seen a proof of this) I'd suggest to prove this topological result.

Comment: @Cameron How can I get the approach to use mean value theorum here? I don't know where to start.

Comment: @S.Dan Note that $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$ doesn't imply that it is continuous on $[a,b]$.

Comment: @S.Dan Consider:
$$\frac{x^2-1}{\vert x^2-1\vert}$$

It's continuous on $(-1,1)$ but not on $[-1,1]$

Comment: Ok i got the brackets wrong, according to the interval given in the question, it is correct right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Claim** $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.

*Proof* $$\lim_{x\to a+}(f(x)-f(a))=\lim_{x\to a+} {f(x)-f(a)\over x-a} (x-a)=\lim_{x\to a+} {f(x)-f(a)\over x-a}\lim_{x\to a+}(x-a)=f'(a)\cdot0=0.$$
Do similarly at $b$.

---

Now suppose that $f(x)<f(a)$ for some $a\in(a,b)$. Use Mean Value Theorem on $[a,x]$, and we get a contradiction since $f'\ge0$ on $(a,x)$.

Do similarly when $f(x)>f(b)$.

Thus we get the result.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the whole point of your problem is to prove that $\mathrm{f}'(x) > 0$ implies that $\mathrm{f}$ is increasing at $x$. Assume that $\mathrm{f}'(x) > 0$, by definition we have
$$\lim_{h \to 0}\left(\frac{\mathrm{f}(x+h)-\mathrm{f}(x)}{h}\right) > 0$$
For sufficiently small, positive $h$ this implies that
$$\frac{\mathrm{f}(x+h)-\mathrm{f}(x)}{h} > 0$$
Multiplying through by $h$ gives $\mathrm{f}(x+h)-\mathrm{f}(x)>0$ and hence $\mathrm{f}(x+h)>\mathrm{f}(x)$.

Comment: This argument (correctly) shows $f$ is "increasing at $x$", but not that $f$ is increasing on some neighborhood of $x$. The latter is generally false without an additional hypothesis, e.g., $f'$ is continuous (and positive) at $x$, or (weaker) that $f'$ is strictly positive in a neighborhood of $x$.

Comment: @user86418 You're right. Well spotted.